# Add support for `ci|` and `da|` (seleting text inside pipes)

Tags: vim

I often use commands like `ci(` and `di{` when editing source code.

Parameters in Ruby blocks are contained inside pipe characters, like `|a, b|`

Is it possible to extend this behavior to add support for `|`, so that commands like `ci|`, `da|` and `yi|` work properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have the following in my vimrc (I have added the `va|` and `vi|` commands for completeness):

```
nnoremap di\| T\|d,
nnoremap da\| F\|d,
nnoremap ci\| T\|c,
nnoremap ca\| F\|c,
nnoremap yi\| T\|y,
nnoremap ya\| F\|y,
nnoremap vi\| T\|v,
nnoremap va\| F\|v,
```

The `,` operator repeats the previous `F`,`f`,`T` or `t` but in the opposite direction. A very useful key!

These mappings can be easily modified to support other delimiters; I use the `$` versions all the time when editing LaTeX.

Comment: I was thinking of writing my own text obj [like this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects). But this is much faster.

Comment: @Thanh DK: Your link is probably more rigorous than my method. My mappings can't handle nested delimiters, for example. But they're good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would use:

```
vnoremap <silent> a<bar> :<c-u>silent! normal! vF<bar>of<bar><cr>
vnoremap <silent> i<bar> :<c-u>silent! normal! vT<bar>ot<bar><cr>
onoremap <silent> a<bar> :normal va<bar><cr>
onoremap <silent> i<bar> :normal vi<bar><cr>
```

Basically setup a operator pending mode (that is the onoremap) which will call the appropriate  visual mode mapping. The visual mode mappings will search backwards to find a `|` with `F|` then go to the other side of the visual selection via the `o` command, then search forwards with `f|` to select the other end of the piped area. The inner mappings are the same but instead of using the `F` and `f` commands you use `T` and `t`.

Sadly these mappings do not work correctly with the `.`, redo command as they inherently rely visual mode mappings which means the `.` command will execute the same command again but only for an area that take up the same amount of space.